# Why doesn't this von Neumann entropy vanish?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-information, entropy, density-operator, quantum-states

I am learning about von Neumann entropy and I understand that it should vanish for a pure state. I tried to calculate it for the pure state whose wavefunction is $$|\psi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} (\lvert\uparrow\rangle + \lvert\downarrow \rangle)$$ and whose density matrix is

$$\rho = \frac{1}{2} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \quad .$$

But what I am getting is

$$S(\rho) := - \mathrm{Tr}[\rho \ln(\rho)]  \\
= - \mathrm{Tr}\left[ \frac{1}{2}  \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}  \begin{pmatrix} \ln\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) & \ln\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \\ \ln\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) & \ln\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \end{pmatrix}  \right] \\
=  - \mathrm{Tr}\left[ \frac{1}{2} \ln\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}  \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}  \right]  \\
= - \frac{1}{2} \ln(\frac{1}{2}) \mathrm{Tr}\left[ \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 2 \\ 2 & 2 \end{pmatrix}  \right] \\
= 2 \ln(2) \neq 0.$$

Could somebody explain to me what I am doing wrong? Isn't this state

Comment: You should include your calculations, else it is not possible to say where you went wrong. Despite that, check-my-work question are generally off-topic.

Comment: I suspect that you took the logarithm of each element of the matrix. But you are supposed to compute the *matrix* logarithm, which is defined via a power series expansion.

Comment: @march yes that is what I did. I will look at what matrix logarithm is. Thank you very much!!

Comment: There is a more suitable method for this case here: The functions of self-adjoint operators are defined via functional calculus... With the (usual) agreement that $0\log 0=:0$ you will immediately find that the von Neumann entropy of a pure state vanishes.

Comment: @TobiasFünke I am not sure what you mean by this exactly. Any reference where I can read about this please? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Orthogonally diagonalize the matrix. The trace of the diagonal equivalent is simpler to evaluate, as functions of a diagonal matrix. What do you find? you don't need a reference.

Comment: I don't have a particular reference, sorry. But this was asked several times here on PSE already...and basically any book on quantum mechanics should cover this.

Comment: @TobiasFünke no it is not in any QM book. I’ve been through Shankar, Sakurai, Merzbacher and Griffiths.

Comment: lol... somewhere functions of hermitian operators are for sure defined...For example, in Nielsen and Chuang, section 2.1.8 these objects are defined.

Comment: Lol you think Nielsen and Chuang is ‘‘any QM book’’.

Comment: I opened a single random book. As I said, this was asked here before several (!) times, so I expect you to do some "research". Simply using Google will help, too,  because this is a fairly established concept, also in the context of QM. This is my last comment.

Comment: @Y2H You are wrong. If you've been through all those books, you really need to read more carefully. The concept of the function of a matrix is readily available [online](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function_of_a_matrix) and in any good QM or mathematical methods book (Griffiths p. 485, Shankar section 1.9, Arfken Weber Harris p. 113, etc.), any introductory probability or statistics book which mentions [Markov processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain), any statistical mechanics book covering [transfer matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfer-matrix_method), etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eigenvalues of $\rho=\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{pmatrix}$ are $1$ and $0$. Evaluating the Von Neumann entropy:
$$S[\rho]=-\mathrm{Tr}[\rho\ln{\rho}]=-\sum_{i}\lambda_i\ln\lambda_i=-0\ln0-1\ln1$$
With the convention $0\ln0=\lim_{x\to0^+}x\ln x=0$, we see that $S[\rho]=0$, as expected.

To give a bit more detail, the result follows from the following useful lemma, for diagonalizable matrices $\rho=Q\Lambda Q^{-1}$:
$$\mathrm{Tr}[\rho^n]=\mathrm{Tr}[Q\Lambda^nQ^{-1}]=\mathrm{Tr}[\Lambda^n]=\sum_i\lambda_i^n$$
Then, since the trace is linear, any analytic matrix function $f(\rho)$ satisfies the following relation, as can be seen from its Taylor expansion:
$$\mathrm{Tr}[f(\rho)]=\mathrm{Tr}\left[\sum_ia_i\rho^i\right]=\sum_ia_i\mathrm{Tr}[\rho^i]=\sum_ia_i\lambda_i^n=\sum_if(\lambda_i)$$